# apache - query string rewrite rule adds percentage symbol

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, regex

I've set up a rule to rewrite a query string.
Although the redirection is correctly performed, a % character is appended to the rewritten query portion of the URL, like so:

index.php?option=com_finder&view=search&f=1&Itemid=365&q=the%2520emperor%2527s%2520new%2520school

instead of

index.php?option=com_finder&view=search&f=1&Itemid=365&q=the%20emperor%27s%20new%20school

The rewrite rule is set as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/site-search\.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchword=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_finder&view=search&f=1&Itemid=365&q=%1 [L,R=301]
```

My aim is to rewrite

site-search.html?searchword=someword

as

full-site-search?q=someword

Is there anything wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to the right format.

Try changing the last part of the last line

from &q=%1 [L,R=301]

to &q=$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Tried that tweak before. Regrettably, it adds the query condition to the URL, not the search phrase. That is to say, q=site-search.html is appended, instead of q=search%20phrase

Comment: Any idea as to what might be wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with Apache/2.2.15. My solution was to use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteMap) with the "unescape" internal function. Using this twice performs a double URL decode, working around the issue.

A demonstration using your example:

```
RewriteMap unesc int:unescape

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/site-search\.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^searchword=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_finder&view=search&f=1&Itemid=365&q=${unesc:${unesc:%1}} [L,R=301]
```